# React-Native StackNavigator best practices

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have for the Authentification: `Login, Register, Password-Recover` screens. For the `Main` page also have: `Home, Profile, About` screens. 
Do I `one` createStackNavigator for every page?

If I do `two` StackNavigator: `One navigator for Authentification screen`, `Second navigator for Main screen` and I use a `createSwitchNavigator` for switch.

Which is best practices and why?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems good to use `createStackNavigator` one and `createDrawerNavigator`.

The reason is because registration is a procedure, it seems good to use a `createStackNavigator`, and because the home screen and the profile are additional, it looks good to use a `createDrawerNavigator`.

- Drawer

  - Main  // not Drawer Item only use Start Screen
  - Home
  - Profile
  - About
- Stack

  - Register
  - Password-Recover
  - Login
  - Drawer
- initialRouteName : Drawer